# How to create bootable .iso image which can be used to install OS in oracle virtual box ? After installation, virtual box should load OS without iso

Tags: boot, system-installation, virtualbox, iso, oracle

I am able to generate iso file from live system but when I try to install it in virtual box, it's not getting installed. It's simply loading the image onto virtual box but if .iso is removed from the path in next bootup, it says "no bootable medium found" since OS has not been installed. My intention is only first time OS installation should be done and from next time onwards, OS must be loaded without iso in virtual box, kindly let me know the procedure to do this.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating what it's as simple as it can be. Installing an OS in Virtualbox, i.e., as a virtual machine is not different than doing it in real hardware. So, knowing that, boot the ISO as you would a USB stick iun real hardware, **install the OS**, remove the ISO.

Comment: I have tried installing OS using .iso file in VirtualBox but still next time again it looks for bootable medium to load OS. My intention is I should have auto bootable iso which can auto boot and install OS at first time then it's not required.

Comment: I have a virtualbox config that does this; but for me it was intention as I setup the VM purposely for that using the HOST settings (*I wanted my VM purely for testing live sessions; ie. check your unstated HOST OS settings*). You've provided no details as to any OS, in fact nothing you have mentioned is on-topic in the few details you have provided (no OS is mentioned; so why ask here?)

Comment: See the Tutorial, including install steps: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox